# How to start SUM() from dynamic row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in `PostgrSQL` which generate the following data:

```
logid subid opid     date        qty1   qty2    
1       1    remove     1.1.15    100    0
2       2    remove     1.1.15    250    0
3       1    add        1.1.15    -450   0
4       3    arrive     1.1.15    320    0
5       1    all        1.1.15    320   500
6       4    remove     2.1.15    5      0
7       5    remove     2.1.15    6      0
8       2    all        3.1.15    50    500
```

Basicly each `opid` is first sorted seperatly, `subid` represend its location in the sorting order... then I merge all ops together and resort them the new sortorder is `logid`. The output is as I presented above.

I need to add a `SUM()` column which operates on cases.
I want it to start from the row which is `subid=1` and `opid='all'`

This is what I wrote:

```
   sum(case when opid = 'all' and subid=1 then qty2+qty1
            when opid = 'all' and subid>1 then qty1
        when opid = 'remove'  then -qty
        when opid = 'add'  then qty
            else 0
       end)  over (order by logid) as A
```

This gives:

```
logid subid opid     date        qty1   qty2    A 
1       1    remove     1.1.15    100    0     -100    / -100
2       2    remove     1.1.15    250    0     -350    / -100-250
3       1    add        1.1.15    -450   0     -800    / -350 + (-450)
4       3    arrive     1.1.15    320    0     -800    / -800 + 0
5       1    all        1.1.15    320   500    20      / -800 +320+500 
6       4    remove     2.1.15    5      0     15      / 20-5
7       5    remove     2.1.15    6      0     9       / 15-6
8       2    all        3.1.15    50    500   59       / 9+50
```

What I want it to be is:

```
logid subid opid     date        qty1   qty2    A 
1       1    remove     1.1.15    100    0     0
2       2    remove     1.1.15    250    0     0
3       1    add        1.1.15    -450   0     0
4       3    arrive     1.1.15    320    0     0
5       1    all        1.1.15    320   500    820      / 320+500
6       4    remove     2.1.15    5      0     815      / 820-5
7       5    remove     2.1.15    6      0     809       / 815-6
8       2    all        3.1.15    50    500    859       / 809+50
```

meaning the sum should start from `logid=5` beacuse this row has `subid=1` and `opid='all'`

The thing is that next time it could be `logid=600` or something else. I don't know in advanced which row will be `subid=1` and `opid='all'`.

Is it possible to start summing for a row which isn't the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible:

```
with ops as (
  select *,
         sum(case when subid=1 and opid='all' then 1 else 0 end)
         over (order by logid) as flag
  from   (YOUR_QUERY)
)
select *,
       sum(case
             when opid = 'all' and subid=1 then qty2+qty1
             when opid = 'all' and subid>1 then qty1
             when opid = 'remove'  then -qty1
             when opid = 'add'  then qty1
             else 0
           end * sign(flag))
       over (order by logid) as A
from   ops
order by logid;
```

The idea is to mark the first row and every subsequent rows by a flag, and then summarize only those rows which are marked.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, it won't SUM anything... to make this work you need to mark all rows after `opid = 'all' and subid=1 `  with `flag=1` as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is `sign(flag)`, so it will work correctly even if there is more than 1 row with `subid=1 and opid='all'`. @SMW, to understand how it works at first try to run the query in the CTE and examine its result.

Comment: I got it... but still don't understand the sign part. flag is SUM of 1s and 0s. How can it have other sign than +?

Comment: If somehow there are several "starting" rows in the table (subid=1 and opid='all'), flag will be 0 in the beginning, then 1 after the first such row, then 2 after the second row etc. Sign function converts that values into 0 and 1. Hence rows before the first "starting" one are multiplied by zero, and other rows are multiplied by 1 (i. e. remain unchanged). Alternatively this part can be rewritten like this: case when flag >= 1 then ... else 0 end.